# can't retrieve related data using DetailView

Tags: python

i want to retrieve related data from a model. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please help! Here is some of my code.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
class SchoolListView(ListView):
model = School  # "school_list" default name of a model to use within templates 
context_object_name = 'schools' # <-- we can set our name for model like this


class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = Student
    template_name = 'my_app/school_detail.html'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from app_for_classes import views

app_name = 'my_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CBView.as_view(), name="base"),
    path("index/", views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path("list/", views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name="list"),
    path("list/<pk>", views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
]
```

school_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'my_app/base_app.html' %}

{% block body_block %}

<h1>Welcome to the School Detail Page!</h1>
<h2>School details:</h2>
<p>Name: {{ school_detail.name }}</p>
<p>Principal: {{ school_detail.principal }}</p>
<p>Location: {{ school_detail.location }}</p>

<h3>Students:</h3>
{% for s in school_detail.students.all %}
<p>{{ s.name }} who is {{ s.age }} years-old</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

and what i get in html is:

Welcome to the School Detail Page!

School details:

**Name**: Max

**Principal**:

**Location**:

**Students**:

Comment: What school are you expecting it to show you?  Where have you specified the school to pick?

Comment: Detail School. Actually I coded along watching a tutorial video and he didn't specify it anywhere saying django itself will identify it by the model name 'school_detail' in the templates so I don't really know where to specify it.

Comment: In order to see a specific school, you have to enter a query that chooses a school.  Are you doing that?

Comment: no, unfortunately i don't and don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think probably you committed an error in your views.py file in SchoolDetailView.

You should use model=School instead of model=Student.

```
...

class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    model = School
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    template_name = 'my_app/school_detail.html'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I am soo grateful for your help. I couldn't fix it for weeks and now i can step on the gas again and continue my way ). Thank you!